# Selecting an option from a huge choices of possibilities

Tags: if-statement

Currently, I am trying to write a backend program to find out the Employer Contribution amount based on the salary of the employee.
However, the amount is not calculated by percentage but it's a fixed amount and there are at least a thousand possibilities.
For example,

wages > $800 and wages < $900 
   contribution amount is $1.70 
wages > $900 and wages < $1000 
   contribution amount is $1.90 
wages > $1000 and wages < $1100 
   contribution amount is $2.00

Since the amount is not based on a formula, I thought the solution is to use a lot of conditions but with this many possibilities, I'm afraid the server will be having a huge load and lag. Is there any advice on this problem?

Comment: In what language?

Comment: If it's always $100 increments, you can divide by 100 and use a lookup table.  If the ranges vary in size, you could put them in a big array and binary search.

Comment: @NateEldredge It's in python. Thanks. I'll try to study lookup table.

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is the server - just do the big `if`. No amount of business logic of this type can be a challenge for the server, even if it runs on a 20 years old hardware. Really. Reading a single character from the network connection will take more resources than going through a thousand `if` branches.